# Regex RewriteRule in Apache 2.4 .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, rewrite, regex

- I want the URL: `http://api.relaunch.local/rest/v1/akb/`
- To rewrite to:  `http://api.relaunch.local/?id=1873&eID=dispatch&controller=akb`

Where `akb` is the variable part.

I tried endless variation without success, here is my last try in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule "^rest/v1/([^/]*)/" "index.php?id=1873&eID=dispatch&controller=$1" [L]
```

This rule is working when I use this testing service: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=eef157ef-0b95-58e2-a42d-6312ee710275

But not on my Apache. I'm on Apache 2.4 with PHP-FPM 7.1

**Rewrite Log:**

```
[Sat Oct 13 19:01:56.394388 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22532:tid 123145530462208] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:55904] 127.0.0.1 - - [api.relaunch.local/sid#7fff0281a5c8][rid#7fff038892a0/initial] [perdir /Users/bandanh/Sites/relaunch.dev/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/bandanh/Sites/relaunch.dev/public/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Oct 13 19:01:56.395768 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22532:tid 123145530462208] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:55904] 127.0.0.1 - - [api.relaunch.local/sid#7fff0281a5c8][rid#7fff038892a0/initial] [perdir /Users/bandanh/Sites/relaunch.dev/public/] applying pattern '^rest/v1/([^/]*)/' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Oct 13 19:01:56.395788 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22532:tid 123145530462208] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:55904] 127.0.0.1 - - [api.relaunch.local/sid#7fff0281a5c8][rid#7fff038892a0/initial] [perdir /Users/bandanh/Sites/relaunch.dev/public/] pass through /Users/bandanh/Sites/relaunch.dev/public/index.php
```

**vhost:**

```
    <Directory /Users/bandanh/Sites/relaunch.local/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </Directory>

    <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/Users/bandanh/Sites/.vhosts/sockets/php-fpm-71.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

Comment: What happens exactly - nothing at all? The directive you posted looks OK - it should "work". Do you have any other directives (perhaps a conflict)? Have you confirmed that you have the appropriate overrides in place for `.htaccess` and that mod_rewrite is installed? "This rule is working when I use this testing service" - Actually, that "testing service" is not producing the correct result. It shows that the _entire_ URL is %-encoded - which is not what happens (if it did, then it is unlikely your site would work).

Comment: During my testing I got any kind of error 404, 500. But the one from my question is now giving me a `Gateway Timeout`, that would point to PHP-FPM. But why is it working with `http://api.relaunch.local/?id=1873&eID=dispatch&controller=akb`, should apache not convert it to the query string and path that to PHP? - I removed everything else from .htacces | mod_rewrite is there.

Comment: A 404 implies the pattern is not matching. A 500 is a syntax error or rewrite loop (check the error log). "Gateway Timeout" - not sure / rewrite loop? "why is it working with `http://api.relaunch.local/?id=1873&eID=dispatch&controller=akb`" - mod_dir issues a subrequest for the DirectoryIndex (`index.php`). The same as if you explicitly included `index.php` in the request. The log entries you've posted would appear to be from later in the request when mod_dir has already issued the subrequest? Try (temporarily) changing your directive to a redirect by adding the `R` flag` - what happens?

Comment: Setting the flag to [R] I get redirected to the correct URL: `http://api.relaunch.local/?id=1873&eID=dispatch&controller=akb`

Comment: Changing it to a redirect tells you that the directive itself (pattern and substitution) are OK. However, do you also have a physical file that has `rest` as its basename? eg. `rest.php`? If you do then `MultiViews` is the problem and you should disable this (you should disable this anyway if you are not using it). ie. Remove `MultiViews` from your `Options` directive.